# Proving a type is a Functor - Inference error?

Tags: agda

I have the following (simplified) data types, and I'm trying to prove a type is a functor.

```
  data T (a : Set) : Set where                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    D  : a → T a                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  record Functor {a b : Set} (f : Set → Set ) : Set where                                                                                                                                                                                   
    field                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
      fmap : (a → b) → f a → f b                                                                                                                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  functor_T : Functor T                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  functor_T = record                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    { fmap = fmap'                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    where                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
      fmap' : ∀ {a b} → (a → b) → T a → T b                                                                                                                                                                                                  
      fmap' f (D a) = D (f a)
```

Yet the compiler highlights `Functor` and prompts the following lines.

```
_a_22 : Set  [ at ... :10,15-22 ]                                                                                                                                                                    
_b_23 : Set  [ at ... :10,15-22 ]
```

What is causing this? Is there some inference issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently your definition of `Functor` specifies that you have the operator `fmap` for two *specific* types `a` and `b`. Presumably what you want is that `fmap` works for *all* types `a` and `b`, so you need to quantify over them in the type of `fmap`:

```
  record Functor (f : Set → Set) : Set1 where                                                                                                                                                                                   
    field                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
      fmap : {a b : Set} → (a → b) → f a → f b
```

To make this work, you also need to change the universe level of `Functor` itself from `Set` to `Set1` (see https://agda.readthedocs.io/en/latest/language/universe-levels.html).

With this changed definition of `Functor`, your definition of `functor_T` should be accepted without changes!

P.S.: It is not recommended to use underscores in identifiers in Agda, since they are reserved for mixfix syntax, see https://agda.readthedocs.io/en/latest/language/mixfix-operators.html